# Paypal Rest API Intenal Server Error 500

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-subscriptions, paypal-rest-sdk

I am using Paypal REST API for Java. I am trying to create recurring payment but it gives me internal server error 500.
Response:

```
Response Code : 500
Response Body : {
    "name"   :"INTERNAL_SERVICE_ERROR",
    "message":"An internal service error has occurred",
    "information_link":"https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#INTERNAL_SERVICE_ERROR",
    "debug_id":"efbbc528aeaaf"
}, change log level to DEBUG for details.
```

Comment: Well, then change log level to DEBUG! (first step towards getting it solved) and update the post with the relevant info

Answer (score 0):

Any time PayPal (or really any HTTP API) returns 50x status, the backend is experiencing a bug or outage. For PayPal, you should contact [Merchant Technical Support](https://www.paypal-techsupport.com/app/ask/) to help triage & escalate internally.

Be sure to include the `debug_id` in the ticket so that the support agent can look up the request that generated this error.